# usage exceeds limit but actually not

Tags: google-calendar-api

REF: Ticket: [#15327597] [Trial] In Trial Customer Inquiry [ ref:_00D00VNwG._500f21CzhlW:ref ]

I checked my quotas and usage in dashboard, but got everything usual.

Error Info:

```
{"error": {"errors": [{"domain": "usageLimits", "message": "Calendar usage limits exceeded.", "reason": "quotaExceeded"}], "code": 403, "message": "Calendar usage limits exceeded."}}
```

I wait 48 hrs till now, but I still can't add events to my calendar using this API. I tried to revoke access and regain but useless.

I think it may caused by an improper code which created 32 secondary calendars in a short period of time. But now it is corrected. I wonder what I can do to release that limit?

PS. I tried to contact Google but got no response, they ask me to ask a question here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Delete my old OAuth API key and recreate new one to solve this problem.